# Gravitational Pull

Tags: physics, gravity

Does anyone know of a tutorial that would deal with gravitational pull of two objects? Eg. a satellite being drawn to the moon (and possibly sling shot past it).

I have a small Java game that I am working on and I would like to implement his feature in it.

I have the formula for gravitational attraction between two bodies, but when I try to use it in my game, nothing happens?

There are two object on the screen, one of which will always be stationary while the other one moves in a straight line at a constant speed until it comes within the detection range of the stationary object. At which point it should be drawn to the stationary object.
First I calculate the distance between the two objects, and depending on their mass and this distance, I update the x and y coordinates.

But like I said, nothing happens. Am I not implementing the formula correctly?

I have included some code to show what I have so far.
This is the instance when the particle collides with the gates detection range, and should start being pulled towards it

```
for (int i = 0; i < particle.length; i++)
    {
        // **************************************************************************************************
        //                                          GATE COLLISION
        // **************************************************************************************************
        // Getting the instance when a Particle collides with a Gate
        if (getDistanceBetweenObjects(gate.getX(), particle[i].getX(), gate.getY(), particle[i].getY()) <= 
            sumOfRadii(particle[i].getRadius(), barrier.getRadius()))
        {   

            particle[i].calcGravPull(particle[i].getMass(), barrier.getMass(), 
                    getDistanceBetweenObjects(gate.getX(), particle[i].getX(), gate.getY(), particle[i].getY()));
        }
```

And the method in my Particle class to do the movement

```
// Calculate the gravitational pull between objects
public void calcGravPull(int mass1, int mass2, double distBetweenObjects)
{   
    double gravityPull;
    gravityPull = GRAV_CONSTANT * ((mass1 * mass2) / (distBetweenObjects * distBetweenObjects));

    x += gravityPull;
    y += gravityPull;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your formula has problems.  You're calculating the gravitational force, and then applying it as if it were an acceleration.  Acceleration is force divided by mass, so you need to divide the force by the small object's mass.  Therefore, `GRAV_CONSTANT * ((mass1) / (distBetweenObjects * distBetweenObjects))` is the formula for acceleration of mass2.

Then you're using it as if it were a positional adjustment, not a velocity adjustment (which an acceleration is).  Keep track of the velocity of the moving mass, use that to adjust its position, and use the acceleration to change that velocity.

Finally, you're using acceleration as a scalar when it's really a vector.  Calculate the angle from the moving mass to the stationary mass, and if you're representing it as angle from the positive x-axis multiply the x acceleration by the cosine of the angle, and the y acceleration by the sine of the angle.

That will give you a correct representation of gravity.

If it does nothing, check the coordinates to see what is happening.  Make sure the stationary mass is large enough to have an effect.  Gravity is a very weak force, and you'll have no significant effect with much smaller than a planetary mass.

Also, make sure you're using the correct gravitational constant for the units you're using.  The constant you find in the books is for the MKS system - meters, kilograms, and seconds.  If you're using kilometers as units of length, you need to multiply the constant by a million, or alternately multiply the length by a thousand before plugging it into the formula.

Comment: Beat me to it. :^)  But I'd recommend against converting to angles, it's easier and usually faster to get the acceleration vector from the separation vector directly.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply, that sounds like it will do the trick. Ill give that a go when I get home.

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm is correct. Probably the gravitational pull you compute is too small to be seen. I'd remove `GRAV_CONSTANT` and try again.
BTW if you can gain a bit of speed moving the result of `getDistanceBetweenObjects()` in a temporary variable.